# How to manage browser features in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I built a site that uses the `$(window).scroll()` jQuery event to programmatically animate in some elements. Since iOS doesn't support this event in the same way, the experience sucks on an iPad.

How do detect the browser in Javascript so I can manage the experience in different browsers? Is this right approach?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a discussion forum. Please refine your question into something more specific.

Comment: Have you looked through http://jquerymobile.com/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question John. Browser detection and browser specific code is evil. It makes your project complex and hard to handle in the future. Read more about feature detection. There are also jQ plugins that help you minic iOS scrolls like [this one](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll)

Easily like this you can add native scrolling:

```
    var scrollContent,
    scrollNav;

function loaded() {
    scrollContent = new iScroll('contentWrapper');
    scrollNav = new iScroll('navWrapper');
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, I know browser detection is bad. My original question was about the 'right' way to do this but got dinged for being to general.

Comment: iScroll which I gave you the link for will allow you to use the webkit properties that iOS does support to provide smooth scroll inside a div etc.

Comment: Some note regarding your question also: The community was right initially you were too generic and here is more about specific questions. Also if you got your answer spend some time improving your question so others can also find it from the site/google ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check iScroll out.